# Azure Active Directory won't logout using ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application and I'm trying to use Azure AD to authenticate. The application redirects to the Microsoft login page but when I logout and then go back to the homepage of the application it automatically logs back in.

I've tried calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout and clearing the cookies but to no avail.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
            {
                var h = new HttpClient();
                var r = await h.GetAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2%3A5001%2F");

                foreach (var cookie in context.Request.Cookies.Keys)
                {
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
                }
            };

            options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = async conext =>
            {
                var t = 1;
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    var result =  SignOut("AzureAD", "AzureADOpenID", "AzureADCookie");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check my way to add Azure AD authentication to ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application. The tool will add the authentication code for you. What you need to do is binding your sign in/out button to the method.

1.Click Connected Services->choose Authentication with Azure Active Directory.

[image]

2.You need to provide a login button for trigger the login page.

[image]

3.Input your tenant name for Domain and choose a way for providing application settings.

[image]

4.Click finish button to complete the configuration.

5.Delete `app.UseBrowserLink()` in Startup.cs.

6.Call `SignOut()` method in `AccountController.cs` to sign out the user. It works well.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
            return SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` library , you can directly redirect user to `https://localhost:xxxxx/AzureAD/Account/SignOut` for sign out , [Source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureAD.UI/src/Areas/AzureAD/Controllers/AccountController.cs) :

```
[HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
public IActionResult SignOut([FromRoute] string scheme)
{
    scheme = scheme ?? AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    var options = Options.Get(scheme);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        options.CookieSchemeName,
        options.OpenIdConnectSchemeName);
}
```

You can now remove the `OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut` event .

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, signing out of Active Directory is now built into the provided Account controller > SignOut action. You can provide a button like this:

```
<a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
```

This generates the url: **/AzureAD/Account/SignOut**

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-6-SignOut