# Azure AD logout issue with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, logout

In my solution, under appsettings.json have mentioned a specific tenant id something like this -

```
//"TenantId": "common",
  "TenantId": "11111111-a111-4111-1111-a11111111111",
```

and have only implemented front channel logout,  when I logout, it is redirected to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut, and it logs out but if I click on the browser back button it logs back into the application which should not happen.

but I observed, if I change my tenant id to common, it properly logs out the user fully from the applicaiton and after logout if I click on browser back button it redirects back to the login page, which is the ideal scenario.

The problem is I can't keep the TenantId as common because I have multiple application under my tenant. So have to specify the exact TenantId

I've looked into the backchannel logout method, but there is no proper documentation from which I can refer.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to add `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller needed and recheck the redirect url  in portal .I have successfully logged out without giving  front channel logout url .Itmay not be required in this scenario.

In app and in portal /signin-oidc

```
{
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdb47",
"ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2002",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
},
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

[image]

If its still happenind ,
Try  by decorating required or all pages with `[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` to prevent back button.

Also don't forget to give [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] verbs for the signout

**References:**

1. [how-to-prevent-the-back-button-after-logout-in-asp-net-core](https://openidauthority.com/how-to-prevent-the-back-button-after-logout-in-asp-net-core/)
2. [azure-active-directory-wont-logout-using-asp-net-core-2-1-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537543/azure-active-directory-wont-logout-using-asp-net-core-2-1-mvc)